# In the Mac terminal, how do I "find" a file and then quickly cd to the parent directory?

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I want to open terminal, find a file or folder, and quickly navigate to that folder or the parent directory of the file.

I can quickly get the path using

```
find ~ -name 'filename.txt'
```

but I can't figure out how to copy that path result into the "cd" command

Is there a way to basically say "cd [path from find command]" or "open [path from find command]"

I'm just using the default terminal in OSX Mountain Lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
cd $(find -name "filename.txt" -type f -exec dirname {} \; | sed 1q)
```

Comment: it's a workable solution, but not clean like I was hoping... oh well, I guess there isn't a simple clean solution like I was hoping

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$ cd `find ~ -name filename.txt -exec dirname {} \;`
```

Comment: Stalker!!!! :-)

Comment: @JS: heh - well *someone*'s got to answer all these `find` questions... ;-)

Comment: Yes Sir!! Now we just got to wait for mods to move it to SuperUser. Sigh!

Comment: I just tried this and got a "No such file or directory error".`$ cd `find ~ -name filename.txt -exec dirname {} \;`` results in an error, but the find command by itself works perfectly:`$ find ~ -name 'filename.txt'` works perfectly.

(I also can't figure out how to use markdown to delineate the code above because the code contains backticks so markdown stops the code formatting part early)

Comment: What happens if you just run `$ find ~ -name filename.txt -exec dirname {} \;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If have added this to `~/.inputrc` to make `\eo` rerun the previous command and insert its output:

```
"\eo": "$(!!)\e\C-e"
```

Or if you use bash 4.0 or later, you can enable `globstar` and press `\eg` to expand patterns like this:

```
cd **/filename.txt
```

You can delete the filename part in both cases with option-delete.